# Change eclipse's quick watch view colors

Tags: eclipse, debugging, colors, expression, watch

i'd like to know how to change the color of eclipse's quick watch view (the topmost on the picture), which is enabled by clicking CTRL+SHIFT+I on a variable or expression while in debug mode.

I'm using eclipse STS 2.8 (guess its based on Indigo,but maybe Helios), on ubuntu and it gets really hard to read the contents as the picture shows.

I guess either the background color or the foreground color would be enough

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That background color cannot be configured in the eclipse because it uses your OS 's ToolTip 's background color .

You can refer [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70599/how-to-change-tooltip-background-color-in-unity) for how to change the tooltip background color in Ubuntu